# Ebean query; using an object in the WHERE clause

Tags: java, sql, ebean

I have a StockItem class that has a field that is a Warehouse object. I want to run an Ebean query to find all StockItem at a certain Warehouse:

```
List<StockItem> result = StockItem.find()
                                  .where()
                                  .eq("warehouse", warehouse)
                                  .findList();
```

But, the result is always size 0, even when there are StockItems in the database with the given Warehouse. I have overridden equals() in the Warehouse class.

If I query for a list of all StockItems and then test for equality on the warehouse fields, I can find the warehouses I'm looking for:

```
String resultString;
List<StockItem> result = StockItem.find().findList();
if(result.get(0).warehouse.equals(warehouse)) {
        resultString = "success";
}
```

Is this the only way to do it?

Edit: Here's my equals() in Warehouse

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(o instanceof Warehouse) {
        Warehouse other = (Warehouse)o;
        return name.equals(other.name) && address.equals(other.address);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: pls show you overridden equals in warehouse

Comment: You should enable Ebean's statement logging to debug what's wrong in your case in DB GUI

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `ebean` is but can you try something like this?

```
List<StockItem> result = StockItem.find()
                                  .where()
                                  .eq("warehouse.id", warehouse.getId())
                                  .findList();
```

Comment: That wouldn't work because in the previous lines I created a new Warehouse object named "warehouse" to use for the query; it wouldn't have an id. Should I be querying to find the proper Warehouse id first and then use it in the StockItem query?

Comment: I was now able to successfully query the warehouses by name to find the proper id and used that in the StockItem query and it retrieved the list of StockItems